# Procedural text embossed label with Geometry Nodes 3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement, procedural, text-object, shader-nodes

[image: Pam&Tommy embossed Text]

Hi there,
I'm trying to make some procedural labels, typewriter style, with some embossing. I'm italian, so I'm struggling to find any exact definition of the style I'm looking for in order to find any worthy tutorials. Casually Disney+ is releasing it's new Pam&Tommy series, and that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to make a procedural node for a label with text string, so that I can easily change the text, and I'd like to get a result such as the Pam&tommy logo, kind of embossed labeller text or something like that. So far I've managed to procedurally shrinkwrap the text onto a plane with raycast, and then I extruded the text with extrude node (in 3.1 alpha), but that's not the result I'm looking for, as the text mesh is crap as usual and it just extrude straight from the projection plane as a solid block, while I want some smoothness on the edges, some dirt, just as a labeller would do. It would be so much easier if there was some string or text node in the shader editor as well, so that I could emboss the text with some procedural textures.
Any ideas on how to get to this result, going full procedural?

Comment: Hi :). You can simply [download such stylized font](https://www.dafont.com/embossing-tape.font) and use it in Blender ;)

Comment: @JachymMichal: Yes, but how to download these fonts PROCEDURALLY....!? :D